# R- Column match, create new column with another column of corresponding value

Tags: r, match, string-matching

I have two data frame:

```
df1<- data.frame(place=c("KARACA ADANA","ASIL BOLU","GAZIANTEP","YUKARI/MERSIN"))
```

```
df2<- data.frame(city=c("ADANA","BOLU","ANTEP","MERSIN"), neighbor=c("KARACA","ASIL","GAZI","YUKARI"))
```

I need to match columns df1$place and df2$neighbor. If df1$place contains the word in df2$neighbor, it should create a new column to df1$newcol by copying the corresponding value of df2$city of matches.

```
df1$newcol <- data.frame(place=c("KARACA ADANA","ASIL BOLU","GAZIANTEP","YUKARI/MERSIN") ,city=c("ADANA","BOLU","ANTEP","MERSIN"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `sapply` from base R:

If you want only whole words to match, you could use a regular expression. `\\b` looks for a word boundary.

```
ind <- unlist(sapply(df2$neighbor, function(x) grep(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"),df1$place)))
ind2 <- rep(1:length(df2$neighbor),
            times = sapply(df2$neighbor, function(x) length(grep(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"),df1$place))))
df1$newcol <- NA
df1$newcol[ind] <- as.character(df2$city[ind2])
df1
#          place newcol
#1  KARACA ADANA  ADANA
#2     ASIL BOLU   BOLU
#3     GAZIANTEP   <NA>
#4 YUKARI/MERSIN MERSIN
#5 YUKARI/MERSIN MERSIN
#6     GAZIANTEP   <NA>
#7     ASIL BOLU   BOLU
#8  KARACA ADANA  ADANA
```

**Sample Data**

```
df1<- data.frame(place=c(c("KARACA ADANA","ASIL BOLU","GAZIANTEP","YUKARI/MERSIN"),
                         rev(c("KARACA ADANA","ASIL BOLU","GAZIANTEP","YUKARI/MERSIN"))))
```

Comment: This really worked !! Thank you so much

Comment: I just realize that this code works when there is an order between matching columns, What if there isn't an order. What should I do in that case

Comment: I am so sorry, but I have one more problem. df1 and df2 don't have the same lenght. For that reason the edited code doesn't work also

Comment: yes, it warns In df1$newcol[ind] <- as.character(df2$city[logical]):
"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: This time works :) You saved my life, thank you sooo much

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing related to this question?

Comment: If my data as below; how can a make two word search in a sentence and if these two word is included in the sentence, than i will take the df2$city

Comment: df1<- data.frame(place=c("GEMİ İNŞAATI VE GEMİ MAKİNELERİ MÜHENDİSLİĞİ PR" , "GEMİ VE DENİZ TEKNOLOJİSİ MÜHENDİSLİĞİ PR","GEMİ MAKİNELERİ İŞLETME MÜHENDİSLİĞİ PR", "ENDÜSTRİ SİSTEMLERİ MÜHENDİSLİĞİ PR", "BİYOSİSTEM MÜHENDİSLİĞİ PR"))

df2<- data.frame(city=c("ENDÜSTRİYEL TASARIM","GEMİ MÜHENDİSLİĞİ","ENDÜSTRİ MÜHENDİSLİĞİ","BİYOSİSTEM MÜHENDİSLİĞİ"), neighbor=c("ENDÜSTRİ TASARIM","GEMİ MÜHENDİS","ENDÜSTRİ MÜHENDİS","BİYO MÜHENDİS"))

Comment: This is quite complicated. I think you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(out = df2$city[str_which(place, df2$city)])
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code

Comment: Code only answers are allowed, but it's encouraged to explain the answer as well. Consider adding some explanation.